# Should scala programmers think of low-level performance?

Tags: performance, scala, low-level

I started to learn Scala language after 8 years of programming in C for embedded-systems and I was very surprised that some of Scala developers doesn't take into account an internals of Scala libraries and how actually their code is executed by the JVM.

I was told that it is not good practice to write your program in pre-optimized way using some knowledge about low-level Scala internals, that it is a task of compiler/JVM developers to make things work fast. So your task as front-end application developer is to write a nice, readable code which is easy to maintain.

I agree that it sounds quite reasonable but it absolutely contradicts with all my experience as C developer.

So should Scala developer dive deep into internals of Scala libraries and JVM and write code using this low-level knowledge as usually C programmer would do?

Comment: Even as a C programmer the first priority should be readability and maintainability. Optimization comes second or third 8or maybe even much later than that), and premature optimization should never happen. I know that small embedded systems are a special case, but the same principle should still be true for that.

Comment: I think this may interest you: http://www.scala-native.org

Comment: This question would probably be a better fit to [Software Engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com). It may even have dupe there already. This could also be language agnostic question, I think this applies to all high level languages.

Comment: Just go with the flow :) Think about turning everything into one, huge, enormous function ;) Being serious, I don't think you should focus on premature optimization in case of Scala. In addition to that, you shouldn't focus on JVM implementation as well. You can find many places in JVM specification where it says something like: "implementation may provide".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You are right but in C you usually know what assembler you will get and you are able to find some compromise between readability and performance. In Scala things are different, usually you are not able to say what byte code will be executed. For example, if you use `flatMap` with `Optiion` how many implicit conversions will be applied and what byte code will be generated?

Comment: Almost all modern language implementations are geared towards extracting efficiency from highly-modular, highly-reusable, well-designed, well-factored, high-level, abstract, expressive, idiomatic code. As long as you write such code you can be reasonably sure that it will end up being executed efficiently. This is true even for C: there are so many different, weird architectures that you really can't predict the performance even of very low-level C code. Think about the AS/400, which has no pointers, no address spaces, no processes, no threads, and no files, so all C code ends up being run …

Comment: in sort of an emulator. Or, since you are asking about Scala, let's look at the Scala ecosystem. There are two production-ready implementations of Scala, Scala-JVM and Scala.js. There's also Scala.NET, which used to be production-ready in the past, and Scala-native which will soon be production-ready. Scala-JVM, Scala.js, and Scala-native have very different performance profiles. Even *within* Scala-JVM, there's the question: *which* JVM? HotSpot has a very different performance profile than J9, Azul, or Excelsior.JET. And the same for Scala.js: Rhino, Nashorn, V8, SpiderMonkey, Chakra, …

Comment: … Nitro, they all behave very different. Heck, even *just* the HotSpot JVM behaves very differently depending on the configuration options. Your job, as a software developer, is to write highly-modular, highly-reusable, well-designed, well-factored, high-level, abstract, expressive, idiomatic code, and trust the Scala compiler designers, JVM designers, JVM JIT compiler designers, and CPU designers to do their job of making such highly-modular, highly-reusable, well-designed, well-factored, high-level, abstract, expressive, idiomatic code run fast.

Answer (score 1):

My intuition is that Scala and C programs are written for different purposes. C code is the tightest, fastest code that is not written in assembly. It is probably used mostly for system programming. It may be longer-lived, slower to write, harder to maintain, requiring a higher level of programmer skill (but I do not have stats on hand). High level languages are used for application programming, where code needs to be written faster, possibly by less-skilled programmers. It needs to be maintained more often. Performance is sometimes an issue, but for many years the cost of hardware went down and it was easier and cheaper to allocate hardware than spend programmer time optimizing the code. In a few special cases, people spend a lot of time optimizing the inner loops of applications written in high level languages. Sometimes, this involves using techniques similar to C: allocating arrays and managing the data in the app instead of relying on garbage collection. It's a big topic, of course.

Comment: or: you can write in Scala-Native and get the best of both worlds. See http://get-scala.org/2.12#scala-native

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the **short answers is**: No, you should not dive deep into the internals of Scala and its libraries. The whole idea is to have a high level of abstraction which allows you to write nicely organized, clean and self-explanatory code.

The long story:
It really depends on what do you want to achieve. For standard use for enterprise application you don't usually need to worry about performance (unless it hits you hard).
On the other hand, if you write a Scala library and some other clients are going to use it, you probably want to optimize performance and deliver a good quality product. For that purpose it is almost necessary to know some internal mechanics.

Nevertheless, there are some things which (to my mind) you should know if you write in Scala, for example some internals of collection library - it is kind of a basic building block for a project in Scala, so it is good to have some knowledge about it.